# "exec source <script>" does not work in tcl

Tags: unix, tcl, csh

I'm trying to call a script in Tcl with the command:

```
exec source <script path>
```

and I get the error

```
couldn't execute "source": no such file or directory
```

How can I call another script from tcl?

Edit: I am running a command I got from another person in my office. I was instructed to run "source  " explicitly with source. So in other words, how would I run any command that would work in cshell, in Tcl?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the other script is written in Tcl or Csh?  I assumed Tcl, others are assuming Csh.

Comment: the script is in cshell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` in csh, like `.` in bash, executes a script without spawning a new process.

The effect is that any variable that is set in that script is available in current csh session.

Actually, `source` is a built-in command of csh, thus not available from tcl `exec`, and using `exec` without `source` would not give the specific `source` effect.

There is no simple way to solve your problem.

Comment: In a nutshell: exec spawns a new process, source executes a script without spawning a new process.

Answer (score 7):

If the script you were given is a cshell script, you can exec it like this:

```
exec /bin/csh $path_to_script
```

In effect, this is what the 'source' command does from within an interactive shell. It's not clear whether this is really what you want to do or not (not exactly, but close enough for this discussion).

The reason you can't exec the source command is that exec will only work on executable files (hence the name 'exec'). The source command isn't implemented as an exectuable file, it is a command built-in to the shell. Thus, it can't be exec'd.

If you really feel the need to exec the source command or any other built-in command you can do something like this:

```
exec /bin/csh -c "source $path_to_script"
```

In the above example you are execing the c shell, and asking it to run the command "source ". For the specific case of the source command, this doesn't really make much sense.

However, I'm not sure any of this will really do what you expect. Usually if someone says "here's some commands, just do 'source ', it usually just defines some aliases and whatnot to be used from within an interactive shell. Those aliases won't work from within Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

source load the source file

you should do:

```
source <script path>
```

If you want to execute it, then you need to call the main proc.

another option would be to do:

```
exec [info nameofexecutable] <scritp path>
```

Comment: See the edit to the question. I have to run the command "source <script> <arg>" as if I were calling it from c-shell.

Comment: Hi Amir,

exec is always going to call an OS executable file. If you need to execute as running from the c-shell or bash or ... you need to use the second option: exec [info nameofexecutable] <script path>

If it's not good enought, describe why ;)

Comment: I get 
"couldn't read file "source": no such file or directory"

Comment: Umm, Amir, what's the result of executing 'info nameofexecutable'?

I'm doing this kind of things in my code in a lot of places and it works. Looks like we're having some kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: The preceding error was when using 'info nameofexecutable'. I get "couldn't read file "source": no such file or directory".

Comment: 'info nameofexecutable' is supposed to return the name (and path) of your tclshell executable. "couldn't read file" is expected when the file you want to open (or source in this case) is not found.

Please try to execute the next script and paste the result, replacing <source script> at the beginning by you real source file.
------------
set mysource "<source script>"
puts "exe: [info nameofexecutable]"
puts "Exists source? $mysource -> [file exists $mysource]"
source "[info nameofexecutable]" "$mysource"
------------

Comment: this would run "source <c-shell script> <arg>" with tclsh which is not what I want... Also, where do I put the arguments for the script?

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion here.  **exec** runs a separate program, possibly with arguments.
**source** is not a separate program, it is another Tcl command which reads a file of Tcl commands and executes them, but does not pass arguments.  If the other script you are trying to call is written to be run on from the command line, it will expect to find its arguments as a list in variable argv.  You can fake this by setting argv to the list of arguments before running source, eg.

```
set argv {first_arg second_arg}
source script_path
```

Alternatively you could use exec to start a whole separate Tcl executable and pass it the script and arguments:

```
exec script_path first_arg second_arg
```

Comment: the second deos assume the script itself has the necessary exec magic at the top to make it executable, otherwise you may need to exec tclsh or wish with it as an argument

Comment: Absolutely right thanks, may need: exec tclsh script_path first_arg second_arg

Answer (score 0):

the error speaks for itself. Make sure you give the correct path name, specify full path if necessary. and make sure there is indeed the file exists in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Recently I wanted to set some UNIX environment variables by sourcing a shell script and stumbled across the same problem. I found this simple solution that works perfectly for me:

Just use a little 3-line wrapper script that executes the source command in a UNIX shell *before* your Tcl script is started.
Example:

```
#!/bin/csh
source SetMyEnvironment.csh
tclsh MyScript.tcl
```